# Read multiple column csv file to nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to read from a csv file and store the data in a nested dictionary.

```
CSV file content

Type, ID, Frequency
Advanced,AAA,30 secs
Advanced,AAA,60 secs
Advanced,BBB,30 secs
Basic,CCC,30 secs
Basic,CCC,60 secs
Basic,DDD,30 secs

Expected output where the 'type' is the higher level key with the values as another dictionary with the ID and frequency as the key/value pair.

{'Advanced': {'AAA':['30 secs', '60 secs'], 'BBB':['30 secs']}, 'Basic': {'CCC':['30 secs', '60 secs'], 'DDD':['30 secs']}}
```

With two columns I got it to work using a defaultdict container.

```
symbols = co.defaultdict(list)
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        symbols[line['Type']].append(line['ID'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dict.setdefault` instead:

```
symbols = {}
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True):
        symbols.setdefault(row['Type'], {}).setdefault(row['ID'], []).append(row['Frequency'])
```

`symbols` becomes:

```
{'Advanced': {'AAA': ['30 secs', '60 secs'], 'BBB': ['30 secs']}, 'Basic': {'CCC': ['30 secs', '60 secs'], 'DDD': ['30 secs']}}
```

Or if you prefer to use `collections.defaultdict`, you should make `symbols` a `defaultdict` of `defaultdict` of lists instead:

```
symbols = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True):
    symbols[row['Type']][row['ID']].append(row['Frequency'])
```